# Syntax for writing strings spread over multiple lines

Tags: objective-c, string-literals

I have a string in my code and I want it to appear like this:

```
NSString *string = @"The string
                          other part of the string is bellow
                          the last part is in the third line";
```

That is, in order to make the code more readable, I want to situate the text on several lines. I think I have to write some symbols after the line breaks, but can't remember which ones. What are they? I've searched quite a lot, but I can't a find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"The string"
                      "other part of the string is bellow"
                      "the last part is in the third line";
```

Comment: Nice! That's what i was looking for! Thanks for quick reply.

And why somebody downvoted? This is what i was looking for.

Comment: Note: You don't need the backslashes (`\\`).